# NetBeans Look&Feel theme is different than how it looks in the IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, look-and-feel

I've been creating a small app with NetBeans IDE and I am trying to change it's default theme, for example to "Nimbus". By the way this is not happening only with Nimbus. I've tried GTK+ too and it's the same.

But what I get when I run the app is quite different than what I see in the design tab (especially buttons) which irritates me for some reason. How can I fix this?

This is the auto-generated code that I've used to change it to Nimbus:

```
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ExtractorFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ExtractorFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ExtractorFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ExtractorFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

*In the picture below, the one above is how it looks **in the design tab of the IDE** and below is how it looks in "**preview**".*

[image: NetBeans theme buttons look different]

*And in the picture below, above is again how it looks in the IDE and below is how it actually looks **when I run the app**.*

[image]

Comment: You need to say what programming language you are using and probably share some relevant code. Are you building a Java application using the NetBeans platform? Just using NetBeans IDE? Something else?

Comment: Yes I am building a Java application. I am adding the relevant code now. Actually I'm using the auto-generated code block for switching the LAF to Nimbus. Thank you.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: I am using Java 8 with NetBeans since it wouldn't work with 10.

Comment: @AndréYuhai Not related to your question, but FYI [NetBeans 9 supports JDK 10](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html).

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank you! I am switching to it soon. :)